# Call a pop up delete modal usin g django DeleteView

Tags: javascript, html, django, modal-dialog

i am using django generic deleteview for deleting my object. i want to delete object from list of objects. There is a trash icon. If user clicks the trash icon a popup modal will come to ensure whether the user wants to delete the object or not. The popup will have a cancel button and a delete button. If the user choses delete button the object will be deleted forever. But the problem is the listview is in one html and deleted popup modal html is in other html. As i am using django generic class for ListView and DeleteView, I have to keep two separate html. now I dont know how can i connect both htmla and show a popup delete option [image]

employe_list.html: this html shows the listview of employees.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'employee/css/master.css' %}">

<div class="">
    <div class="table-wrapper">
      <div class="table-title">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h2><b>Employees</b></h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <a href="{% url 'employee:employee-add' %}" data-target="exampleModal" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal">
                            <span ></span>
                            <i class="material-icons"></i>
                            <span data-feather="plus"></span>Add New Employee
                        </a>
            <!--<a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons">&#xE15C;</i> <span>Delete</span></a>-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <span class="custom-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">
                                <label for="selectAll"></label>
                        </span>
            </th>
                        <th>ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Department</th>
                        <th>Designation</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <!-- Loop for showing employee list in a table-->
          {% for employee in employees %}
          <tr>
            <td>
              <span class="custom-checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="options[]" value="1">
                  <label for="checkbox1"></label>
                </span>
            </td>
                        <td>{{employee.e_id}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.first_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{employee.last_name}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.email}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.address}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.phone_number}}</td>
                        <td>{{employee.department}}</td>
                        <td>{{employee.designation}}</td>

            <td>
              <a href="{% url 'employee:employee-update' employee.id %}" class="edit" data-toggle="modal">
                                <i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit"></i>
                                <span data-feather="edit-2"></span>
                            </a>
              <a href="{% url 'employee:employee-delete' employee.id %}" date-target="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="delete" data-toggle="modal">
                                <i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"></i>
                                <span data-feather="trash"></span>
                            </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>

            <div class="">
                {% if is_paginated %}
                <ul class="pagination">
                    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                        <li><a  href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}"><span data-feather="chevron-left"></span></a></li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li class="disabled"><span data-feather="chevron-left"></span></li>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% for i in paginator.page_range %}
                        {% if page_obj.number == i %}
                            <li class="active"><span class="pagination-number pagination-current">{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
                        {% else %}
                            <li><a class="pagination-number" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                        <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}"><span data-feather="chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li class="disabled"><span data-feather="chevron-right"></span></li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
    </div>

<div id="deleteEmployeeModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content"
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

employee_delete.html: This html shows the delete modal:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'dashboard/css/master.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>
  <h2>Employee delete </h2>

        <form method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Employee</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Are you sure you want to delete these Records?</p>
            <p class="text-warning"><small>This action cannot be undone.</small></p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">
          </div>
        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

views.py:

```
class EmployeeDeleteView(DeleteView):
    """
    Deletes a created employee
    """
    template_name = 'employee/employee_delete.html'
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('employee:employee-list')

    def get_object(self):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")
        return get_object_or_404(Employee, id=id_)

    def delete_modal_view(request):
        return render(request, "employee_delete.html")
```

Comment: Try the django-bootstrap-modal-forms 2.2.0 library

Comment: It is solved. thanks

Comment: how it was solved? can you share the answer here?

Comment: @statsconchris I solved it using ajax function.